# how to 'browserSync + LiveReload + watch' in gulp @4

Tags: npm, gulp, watch, browser-sync, gulp-sass

I'm trying to write a gulp file that do the following:

1. watch the task for any changes.
2. compile SCSS and minify css and javascript by calling some tasks
3. Reload the browser vie browserSync

**So I came up with following pice of code:**

```js
gulp.task('watch', function() {

  browserSync({
    server: {
      baseDir: [paths.base.root]
    }
  });

  gulp.watch(paths.assets.scss, gulp.series('compile:scss'));
  gulp.watch(paths.assets.css + '**/*.css', gulp.series('minify:css'));
  gulp.watch(paths.assets.js, gulp.series('minify:js'));


  gulp.watch(paths.base.html, browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch(paths.assets.js, browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch(paths.assets.css + '**/*.css', browserSync.reload); 
  gulp.watch(paths.assets.imgs, browserSync.reload); 
});
```

In this pice of code the first three tasks are working but browser only reload one time.